# What does a walker menu mean?

Tags: menus

I don't understand what is a walker menu in [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L67) function means. [The document](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu) doesn't say much about it. What does it looks like in graphic or HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walker_Nav_Menu is the core class to handle navigation menus.
You can use it to handle your navigation menu, or you can create your own children class that extends this class.

If you decide to use your own class, then you must pass an instance as an argument when you use wp_nav_menu()

```
class myWalkerClass Extends \Walker_Nav_Menu {
 //overwrite any method as you see fit.
}

$args = [
  'container' => 'div',
  //...other arguments,
  'walker' => new myWalkerClass(),
];

wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

if you want to let the core class handle your nav menu, just dont pass it as an argument.

EDIT: Example of a child PHP class:

```
class myWalkerChildClass Extends \Walker_Nav_Menu {

  /*there are 4 methods that can be overwritten ( meaning that if you declare them here, you are using your own method, and if you dont declare them here, you are using the original method from Walker_Nav_Menu parent PHP class.*/


    /*please note that fore very method, $output is passed by reference, meaning you can modify $output directly in the method, and changes carry over to the next method until it is printed.*/

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args ) {

        $output .= "\n<ul>\n"; //here you are starting a new list,
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args ) {
        $output .= "</ul>\n"; //here you are closing a list,
    }


    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        $output. = "<li>".esc_attr($item->label); //here you are starting a new item within a list.
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n"; //and finally closing the item
    }
}

}
```

for a more indepth tutorial, check [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401):

Comment: Do you have a result from your example. What Walker does is still vague to me. For example, the `container` in `$args` will allow us to wrap or unwrap HTML element around menu right. So what does the Walker do? What do you mean children class, the OOP class or the HTML class? If it's OOP, then what can I do with it? Can I change the HTML from `<li>` to `<dd>` or `<dt>`?

Comment: Yes, you can do pretty much everything you want with the child PHP class, including changing the opening tags of each element . I edited my answer, with a very simplified example, and also with a link that you can check for a more in-depth tutorial